# Error installing chrome remote desktop on headless debian buster linux host

Tags: debian, google-chrome, debian-buster, headless

I have a debian buster host (not on Google Cloud) and I am following the steps in this tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine

However, when trying to authorize chrome remote desktop through https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless/, I get the following errors:

```
Enter a PIN of at least six digits: 
Enter the same PIN again: 
[1222/160831.831679:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(559)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
[1222/160831.950166:INFO:host_stopper.cc(38)] Stopping existing host: 67956fc6-16c6-4788-baff-6012355f9015. This may take a few seconds.
[1222/160831.992140:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(559)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
[1222/160832.074308:ERROR:service_client.cc(132)] Received error code: 5, message: Requested entity was not found.
[1222/160832.140642:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(99)] The daemon is not currently running
```

I am unsure of what to do or how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Isn't chrome remote desktop intended for google cloud? Also, you don't need Google for a remote desktop on linux.

Comment: Well I mostly liked it because I thought it would have easier installation. But I guess I will go with guacamole and vnc.